# Best method to make search for any number of <space>s sargable

Tags: sql-server, indexing, sql-server-2012

We are looking to improve an SQL WHERE clause that filters NULLs and values containing only blanks, but finding it difficult to allow the solution to use the index on that column, thus making sargable.

Original:

```
where isnull(ltrim(rtrim(ean_code)), N'') <> N''
```

Proposed:

```
where EAN_CODE is not null and EAN_CODE NOT IN ('', ' ', '  ', '   ', '    ', '     ')
```

Is there a better solution?

Comment: If a value contains only blanks, then `LEN(value) = 0` and `value = ''`, thanks to a quirk of SQL where trailing blanks don't count. You may be able to use that to your advantage. (As in, a simple `EAN_CODE <> ''` should suffice for all cases.)

Comment: @JeroenMostert Unfortunately, functions based on columns will not use indexes - not sargable.

Comment: @cloudsafe But `EAN_CODE <> ''` will use your index.

Comment: So don't use functions? Like I said, your proposed solution is encompassed by `WHERE EAN_CODE <> ''`, which 1) excludes `NULL` by virtue of comparing with an actual value and 2) all blank values by virtue of the trailing blank rule and 3) allows the use of an index. Note that if the majority of your values is not blank (as you'd expect), SQL Server may still effectively just scan the index rather than seek it due to the query not being selective, but that's another issue. If that is your problem, you need a different strategy anyway.

Comment: @JeroenMostert You are absolutely right. This will save so much time, effort and performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jeroen Mostert wrote in the comments, all you need to do is check if the column is not equal to an empty string.

Create and populate sample table (**Please** save us this step in your future questions)

```
DECLARE @T AS TABLE
(
    Id int identity(1,1),
    Col varchar(10)
)

INSERT INTO @T (Col) VALUES
(''), 
(' '), 
('  '), 
('   '),
('    '),
('z'), 
(NULL)
```

The query:

```
SELECT *
FROM @T
WHERE Col != ''
```

Results:

```
Id  Col
6   z
```

[You can see a live demo on rextester.](http://rextester.com/KDEOGJ69621)

Comment: Note that if `Col != ''`, then by definition, `Col IS NOT NULL` (irrespective of `ANSI_NULLS`, fortunately). You may still feel the need to write it out explicitly for clarity, but it'll make no difference for the query.

Comment: @JeroenMostert good point. I didn't think about that. Editing.

Answer (score 0):

This should be sufficient

```
declare @t table
(
    Val VARCHAR(20)
)

INSERT INTO @t
VALUES(null),(''),(' '),('   '),('Sample'),(' Sample1'),('Sample2 '),(' Sample3 ')

select
    *
    from @t
       WHERE LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(Val,'')))<>''
```

or You may also try this

```
select
    *
    from @t
       WHERE LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(ISNULL(Val,''),' ',''))))<>0
```

Output

[image]

Comment: @Jayasuraya Satheesh That is not sargable so will not make use of the index.